# Personal statistics about failed/passed audits of the review queues

Tags: support

Under `profile -> all actions -> reviews` I find a list with my reviews and the choices I made - is there a view/SEDE for my personal statistic regarding failed and passed audits?

Comment: That information isn't kept in SEDE and there's no page accessible on the site that summarises that information either...

Comment: The expected ratio of passed audits needs to be very close to 100% for a reviewer to remain valuable. If the number of non-passed audits is significant, a user will end up being banned. Hence, statistics about that doesn't seem particularly useful, IMO.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the straight forward reply - Feel free to post an answer and I'll gladly accept it..

Comment: @yivi Fortunatly I read every review carefully and should have quite a good statistics - haven't received a ban yet ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix well... there's no "official" way but I'll leave it a bit for someone to possibly pop along and say: "There's no official way... but have a look at this userscript" or similar :)

Comment: @iLuvLogix Awesome. That means you are very close to 100%. If you deviated much from that, pretty sure you'd been warned at some point. :)

Comment: Review stats would be useful, though. Guesstimation on the efficacy of my close review (by just looking through my history) shows that about 20-30% of the questions where I vote to close actually get closed. It would be nice and demotivating to plot this in time, I have the feeling it's steadily decreasing.

Comment: @ErikA - I think that's a different issue.  Though I would agree that it would be interesting to know if there are significant differences in reviewers' vote patterns; e.g. in relation to reputation, or nos audit failures.